# Connecting to Service Fabric using Python SDK and certificate

Tags: python, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to use Python SDK for Service Fabric in order to get a list of application types from the cluster.

The cluster is not Azure AD enabled thus in powershell I connect to it with a certificate.

I am not sure how to do it with python.

I have owner permissions on the subscription and I am using the right SPN account to fetch information, other python operations on the resource group or the cluster object return me output.

```py
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.servicefabric import ServiceFabricManagementClient

tenant_id = os.environ['AZURE_TENANT']
spn_client_id = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT']
spn_secret = os.environ['AZURE_SECRET']
sub_id = 'some-subscription-id'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = spn_client_id,
    secret = spn_secret,
    tenant = tenant_id
)

sf_client = ServiceFabricManagementClient(credentials, sub_id)
sf_api_client = ServiceFabricClientAPIs(credentials, sub_id)
```

This code works:

```
sf_client.clusters.get('some-rg-name', 'some-cluster-name')
```

Because I have permissions on the subscription, so Azure Api returns values.

Checking the applications on the cluster is a different matter, I can't enumerate application types, with this code for example:

```
sf_client.application_type.list('some-rg-name', 'some-cluster-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the permission, the `Owner` role is enough.

There is a mistake with your code, it should be `sf_client.application_types.list`, not `sf_client.application_type.list`, it works on my side.

```
apptype = sf_client.application_types.list('some-rg-name', 'some-cluster-name')
print(apptype)
```

[image]

---

**Besides**, if you get the `'value': []` in the result, it also means success, just because there is no `application type` resource in your cluster. You can check the result via this REST API [`Application Types - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/application/applicationtypes/list) first.

**Update**:

Use this api [`Application Types - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/application/applicationtypes/createorupdate#code-try-0) to create a new application type, specify the parameters and the request body should be like .

```
{
  "location": "eastus",
  "tags": {}
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Response:

[image]

Then use this api [`Application Types - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/application/applicationtypes/list) or `sf_client.application_types.list('some-rg-name', 'some-cluster-name')` to list the application types.

[image]

Comment: When I run your code modification I get- AttributeError: 'ServiceFabricManagementClient' object has no attribute 'application_types', when i run dir(sf_client) i get " 'application', 'application_type'" as part of the results of the object

Comment: i forgot to mention that i do have application types and instances on the cluster, i can see them in service fabric explorer or when i connect to the cluster using powershell with a provided certificate as authentication and authorization (admin cert). If I run the command as in my post, I do get an object, with nothing in the value field, the object i get for "application_type" is pasted below.. maybe there is a slight difference in their naming in the python sdk?  <azure.mgmt.servicefabric.operations.application_type_operations.ApplicationTypeOperations

Comment: @Pixel Try the `azure-mgmt-servicefabric` with `0.4.0` version. https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-servicefabric/

Comment: pip upgraded to 0.4.0, the naming is just different now, but same result. i also used the api from the link you posted and postman, no value, but there are applications on the cluster

Comment: @Pixel Are you sure? Could you use this api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/application/applicationtypes/createorupdate to create a new Application Type, then have a try? Just click the `Try it` button, follow this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/application/applicationtypes/createorupdate#put-an-application-type).

Comment: I tried both creating application type and an application instance. When creating application type i get - internal server error - 'an error as occured' as return, when i try to create an application instance using for example 'myapptype/newname' as the name, i get no return whatsoever back, i do have 'myapptype' app type created in cluster and i ran the right api call.. i just cant paste it here, the text will go haywire. i don't understand how creating an apptype this way would work, it is a new app type, i'd preferably want to upload a whole new application page with a manifest etc..

Comment: @Pixel You need to specify the request body with `{
  "location": "eastus",
  "tags": {}
}`, otherwise you will get a internal server error, could you try again?

Comment: @Pixel See my update. It is not related to `Application`, it is just `Application type`. Could you follow my steps and see if you can get it?

Comment: I managed to create an application type now, the weird thing is that i do not see it in the sf explorer or azure portal, if i run the list command through the api, the only application type that i get back is the one i just created.. i am really buffled at how this is possible! I am looking at the right cluster, and i have put all the details in the "try it now" fields manually

Comment: @Pixel It is wired, not sure why. Anyway the code works.

Comment: The code does, but my question is primarily about whether anyone managed or knows how to connect using a client certificate because the current api/sdk doesn't present me with the right information. Your response is greatly appreciated :)